# Add Onclick To List Generated From Model

Tags: android, listview, kotlin, model, onitemclicklistener

My aim is to show information in another activity with itemclick in a listview as below. But I cannot send information to the other screen with putextra. Because I created my list from a model. How can I solve this. Please help.

```
  val listView=findViewById<ListView>(R.id.listView)
    val list=ArrayList<CustomerModel>()

    listView.setOnItemClickListener { adapterView, view, i, l ->

        val intent=Intent(applicationContext,CustomersDetails::class.java)
      intent.putExtra("Name",list[i]) // That's not Define
        startActivity(intent)
    }
```

Model.kt

```
class CustomerModel(val title:String, val description:String,val img:Int) {
```

}

Comment: Can you share your model class? You should make your model `Parcelable` or `Serializable`.

Comment: I shared model class.

Comment: Add `@Parcelable` to your model class. like `@Parcelable class CustomerModel`

Comment: I add @Parcelable in model class that's you said exactly.But still I'm not define intent.putExtra.

Comment: Sorry I wrote it wrong, you should implement Parcelable like class `CustomerModel : Parcelable`

Comment: Thank you sir.I did it.